# Use knockout.js to data-bind javascript associative array across columns

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

In C# DestopModel.cs, we have defined a DesktopViewModel, with a number of Designs.

```
public class DesktopViewModel
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }              
        public List<DesktopDesignViewModel> Designs { get; set; }
        // ...
}
```

In our script.cshtml, we have converted the DesktopViewModel to a knockout view model vew ko.mapping.
We also have a DesignScore function, that does some calculations and returns a set of scores 
for each design across a number of categories.

```
@model DesktopViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Desktop = {

        ViewModel: null,

        Initialize: function () {
            // create knockout model
            Desktop.ViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

            // ...

            this.ViewModel.DesignScore = function (design) {
                return ko.computed(function () {

                    var ClimateChange = 0;
                    var OceanAcidification = 0;
                    var OzoneDepletion = 0;
                    var BiogeochemicalCycles = 0;
                    var FreshWaterUse = 0;
                    var ChangeInLandUse = 0;
                    var BiodiversityLoss = 0;
                    var ChemicalPollution = 0;
                    var AtmosphericAerosols = 0;

                    // ... some calculations

                    return {
                        "ClimateChange": ClimateChange,
                        "OceanAcidification": OceanAcidification,
                        "OzoneDepletion": OzoneDepletion,
                        "BiogeochemicalCycles": BiogeochemicalCycles,
                        "FreshWaterUse": FreshWaterUse,
                        "ChangeInLandUse": ChangeInLandUse,
                        "BiodiversityLoss": BiodiversityLoss,
                        "ChemicalPollution": ChemicalPollution,
                        "AtmosphericAerosols": AtmosphericAerosols
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In our view.cshtml, I am trying to display the results in a table.

```
                        des1    des2    des3
=================================================
Climate Change          1560    936     3588
Ocean Acidification     1560    936     3588
Ozone Depletion         0.1     0.2     0.3
...
```

Here is the way I am currently data-binding the results:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2 text-center">&nbsp;</th>
            <!-- ko foreach: Designs -->
            <th class="text-center">
                <h5 data-bind="text: Name"></h5>
            </th>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="top-border-row">
            <td class="text-center">
                <h4>Climate Change</h4>
            </td>
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: $root.Designs, as: 'design' } -->
            <td class="text-center">                                                                
                <h4 data-bind="text: $root.DesignScore(design)().ClimateChange"></h4>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->                            
        </tr>

        <tr class="top-border-row">
            <td class="text-center">
                <h4>Ocean Acidification</h4>
            </td>
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: $root.Designs, as: 'design' } -->
            <td class="text-center">                                                                
                <h4 data-bind="text: $root.DesignScore(design)().OceanAcidification"></h4>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->                            
        </tr>

        // ...                            

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Right now, I am iterating through every design for each category, and calling DesignScore nine times in my data-binding, even though a single call to DesignScore function would return all the results across all categories for a design.

**Question:** Is there a way to foreach through each design once, and data-bind the results across the categories down a column?
HTML only has a tr elements, but not a tc for column.

**UPDATE1:**

I have split the DesignScore function up into separate functions, and data-bind the results of each in a knockout template.  The resulting table through is one column though.

Output:

```
des1  des2  des3
==================

1560 (ie. des1's Climate Change)

0.1  (ie. des1's Ozone Depleition)

3900.7 (ie. des2's Climate Change)

0.2

3588.6

0.3
```

Code:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2 text-center">&nbsp;</th>
        <!-- ko foreach: Designs -->
        <th class="text-center">
            <h5 data-bind="text: Name"></h5>
        </th>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'impact-category-template', foreach: $root.Designs, as: 'design' }"></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="impact-category-template">    
      <tr>
          <td class="text-center"> 
              <h4 data-bind="text: $root.ClimateChange(design)"></h4>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="text-center"> 
                  <h4 data-bind="text: $root.OzoneDepletion(design)"></h4>
          </td>
      </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It really shouldn't be that hard.  I don't fully grasp your data model but I would try to model each row as a object and use a template to render it.  Simplify as much as possible.

as for the calculations, is it similar for each category?  If its calced once, I don't think a computed is needed.

```
function DesktopDesignViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.categoryName= ko.observable();
  self.dest1= ko.observable();
  self.dest2= ko.observable();
  self.dest3= ko.observable();
  //may be used as constructor to fill in observables
  self.superCalc = function(){}; 
}


<script id="resultsTemplate" type="text/html">
   <tr>
       <td data-bind="text: categoryName"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: dest1"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: dest2"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: dest3"></td>
   </tr>
</script>

<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Dest1</th>
       <th>Dest2</th>
       <th>Dest3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'resultsTemplate', foreach: Designs}"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I wasn't sure how your suggested solution would mapped to my data model.  For one thing, your dest1, dest2, and dest3 fields, if they correspond to my des1, des2, des3 above, these are design names, and they are dynamic for each design.  The DesignScore() function returns the set of scores across the nine categories for one design (which we pass in).  It returns a ko.computed value, because it depends on other ko.computed observables.  And I don't see the solution making use of the return values of DesignScore() in the binding.

Comment: After reading the knockout documentation, using the template may be a solution to my code redundancy problem, I will probably have to break the existing DesignScore (I didn't design the data model), so that ClimateChange, OceanAcidification ... etc, are separate functions of the ViewModel, rather than returning everything via a single DesignScore function as a javascript associated arrays.  And then I can try to bind each individual DesignScore function per category separately.

Comment: I tried to break up my DesignScore function, and apply the knockout template as in UPDATE1.  But when I foreach through my designs (each design should occupy a column), my output just stacks up to a single column.  So it still doesn't work.

Comment: when you view source does it have the right values, just in the wrong position?

Comment: yes right values, but I don't know how I could format the values in the same way as I had in the OP given that foreach binding on the design with any tr elements in the template would automatically stack the designs and the associated impacts row-wise on top of each other.